# Problema con Validate Rules Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Tengo una Tabla `Role` con los atributos `id` y `Role`.

A algunos de los roles les hago `softdelete`.

Ahora bien, cuando quiero crear un role nuevo tengo las siguientes reglas:

```
public function rules() {
  return [
    'role' => 'required|unique:role,role|alpha'
  ];
}
```

Si el role no existe lo va crear.

```
public function store(NewRoleRequest $request) {        
  $request['role'] = strtoupper($request->input('role'));
  $this->roleRepo->create($request->all());
  return redirect()
    ->route('role.create')
    ->with('create-success', 'Role agregado correctamente.');      
}
```

Lo que no puedo logar hacer es que si el Role ya existe en la base de datos pero tiene `softDelete`, que lo restaure. Es decir, cuando va al método `store` y comprueba las reglas, ver alguna forma si ya esta ese role que quiero crear como `sofdelete`, si esta que haga el `restore()`, sino que lo cree.

Ademas si el atributo es unique, me redirecciona automáticamente a la vista de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de solucionarlo, una es consultar el modelo antes de realizar la validación, mirar si el role existe en los "trashed", restaurarlo y no validar unique. En caso contrario, validar unique.

La solución sería algo así (no está probada, es para guiarte):

```
public function rules()
{
    $trashedRole = Role::onlyTrashed()
                       ->where('role', $this->input('role'))
                       ->first();

    // si no está en los elementos borrados, validamos unique
    if ($trashedRole->isEmpty()) {
        return [
            'role' => 'required|unique:role,role|alpha'
        ];
    }

    // restauramos y no validamos unique
    $trashedRole->restore();
    return [
        'role' => 'required|alpha'
    ]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Observando un poco otras respuestas, creo que se trata de un problema de arquitectura de software.
El propósito de softdelete es la posibilidad de dejar inactivo un registro para posteriormente restaurarlo en el futuro.

Entonces, si usarás softdelete y necesitas que sea único, solo debes darle uso en restaurar y actualizar.

**Fuente:**

[How to use a unique validation rule / unique columns with soft deletes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458681/laravel-4-how-to-use-a-unique-validation-rule-unique-columns-with-soft-delet?lq=1)

[Laravel Soft Delete Unique column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424294/laravel-soft-delete-unique-column-name)